# Accurate definition for Big(O)'s

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I was taking notes on a class I'm taking about Data Structures & Algorithms.

The instructor gave us the following definition for "O(n) Time Complexity":

> O(n) - Linear Time 
> An algorithm is considered to have a complexity of O(n) when its execution time grows linearly in proportion to the size of the input (n).

With the following graph explaining associated to the definition: 
[image]

I really don't like this definition very much, because it only takes into account Time. 
We all know Big(O) is about **Time & Space** Complexity.

So this is a more general definition I thought about:

> O(n) 
> An algorithm is considered to have a complexity of O(n) when the number of operations executed by the algorithm grows linearly in proportion to the size of the input (n).

In this way the definition will be also more coherent with the graph.

What do you guys think? What's the best definition in your opinion? 
I know this is a very important topic so I want my notes to be written in the best way possible!

Comment: Why complicate it? Executing operations takes time.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think it's complicating it, 
I'm new to the topic and when BigO was first presented to me with T&S Complexity and I then saw this definition I was a bit confused "where's space then?".

Comment: The graph is wrong to begin with. There also can be 5, 10 or 10,000 operations per item and the complexity will still be `O(n)`.

Comment: Your instructor gave the definition for "O(n) Time Complexity". So it is indeed about time. Space complexity is a different property.

Comment: Hello :) Where is space in that definition?

Comment: @0009laH
My definition that cites "operations" both embraces Time & Space complexity in an implicit way...an operation could be logging something for n times or allocating space for n times (items), or at least that's the way I see it, feel free to share your thoughts tho! :)

Comment: I think that it is impossible to make a correlation between memory space and time for an algorithm. E.g. sorting algorithms for a set of N elements --> **quick sort** has an average memory complexity of O(log(n)) and an average time complexity of O(n*log(n)), which value will represent the algorithm complexity ? Then how would we compare algorithm complexities is we choose to use **bubble sort** instead? (average O(n²) in time and O(1) in space)

Answer (score 6):

### Clarification

> We all know Big(O) is about Time & Space Complexity.

Thats not entirely correct either. Big-O in itself is a general math construct applied to functions. In itself, it has nothing to do with programming or algorithms. How you make use of that tool is entirely up to you. You can use it for much more than just time and space of algorithms.

### Definition

The *correct* definition of Big-O (and its friends small-o, big-omega, small-omega and Theta) is of course the full mathematical definition that leaves no space for interpretatation. That is (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)):

[image: big-o definition]

Reading:

> `f in O(g)` iff there exists a constant `C > 0`, a number `x_0 > 0`, such that for all `x > x_0` it holds that `|f(x)| <= C * |g(x)|`

### Explanation

In simple terms, this means that the function `f` **asymptotically grows** less (or equal) than `g`.

- asymptotically - we do not care for how `f` behaves in the beginning, only when it approaches infinity
- growth - we do not care about absolute values of `f` and `g`, we only compare their growth.

As you see, it only talks about functions, not code or algorithms. How you bridge that gap to apply this tool is entirely up to you. In programming practice, we often attempt to formulate our codes running time (or also space consumption) in terms of a mathematical function and then apply this tool on it. However, we can also apply it to much more.

### Note

Some note of caution. Be aware of the limitations of Big-O. An algorithm that takes a year to execute can still be in `O(1)`, if it does not change its execution time depending on the input. So just because one algorithm is in `O(1)` and another in `O(n^5)`, does not necessarily mean that former is *better*. It might entirely be the case that the *worse* algorithm (in terms of complexity) is the *better* algorithm when applied to problems of reasonable size.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you've been very clear but I do know that it is more a math related topic than a programming one, the definition I was looking for tho was one embracing the programming essence of BigO...

Comment: I get that, but you are asking for a vague use case already. You can use Big-O to measure more things than just time and space complexity, even when talking about programming. For example, it can tell you thread usage growth. Or percentage growth of how inbalanced a tree is. There are too many programming related use cases to count them all.

Comment: I admit I was way too vague and I realized that later since it's one of my first question on stackoverflow, but if we were to apply this on algorithms time & space complexity, would you agree that the definition I gave is good for that or you would suggest anything else? 

I need this to prepare for coding interviews so I'm more interested on how to use and define it in the scope of DSA.

Comment: @matthewbolds What you wrote is how time complexity is generally understood, yes. I.e. the function under analysis would be a function denoting the amount of operations. That is sorta vague though, as in most languages the amount of operations can not be determined accurately. Since constants (due to how Big-O is mathematically defined) sorta fall away anyways, that is usually not a concern though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Time vs space.

In complexity theory if an algorithm is `O(n)` in time complexity it's  also `O(n)` in memory complexity. This is because the model in which the algorithms operate does not allow allocating blocks of memory as a separate operation. Basically only writes count as memory usage, so the running time of the algorithm limits memory usage.

This might seem artificial but it models real life algorithms quite well.

Obviously, an algorithm can have **lower** memory complexity than time complexity.

2. `O(n)`

The most practical definition is that for sufficiently large values of `n` the running time is bound by `c*n` where `c` is a constant. See the other answer for a much more detailed explanation.